# Parsing a json column in tsv file to Spark RDD

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to port an existing Python (PySpark) script to Scala in an effort to improve performance.

I'm having trouble with something troublingly basic though -- how to parse a json column in Scala?

Here is the Python version

```
# Each row in file is tab separated, example:
# 2015-10-10 149775392 {"url": "http://example.com", "id": 149775392, "segments": {"completed_segments": [321, 4322, 126]}}

action_files = sc.textFile("s3://my-s3-bucket/2015/10/10/")
actions = (action_files
    .map(lambda row: json.loads(row.split('\t')[-1]))
    .filter(lambda a: a.get('url') != None and a.get('segments') != None and a.get('segments').get('completed_segments') != None)
    .map(lambda a: (action['url'], {"url": action['url'], "action_id": action["id"], "completed_segments": action["segments"]["completed_segments"],}))
    .partitionBy(100)
    .persist())
```

Basically, I'm just trying to parse the json column and then transform it into a simplified version that I can process further in `SparkSQL`

As a new Scala user, I'm finding that there are dozens of libraries json parsing libraries for this simple task.  Doesn't look like there is one in the stdlib.  From what I've read so far, looks like the languages strong typing is was makes this simple task a bit of a chore.

I'd appreciate any push in the right direction!

PS. By the way, if I'm missing something obvious that is making the PySpark version crawl, I'd love to hear about it!  I'm porting a Pig Script from Hadoop/MR, and performance dropped from 17min with MR to over 5 and a half hours on Spark!  I'm guessing it is serialization overhead to and from Python....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to pass data to SparkSQL anyway and you're sure that you don't have malformed fields (I don't see any exception handling in your code) I wouldn't bother with parsing manually at all:

```
val raw = sqlContext.read.json(action_files.flatMap(_.split("\t").takeRight(1)))

val df = raw
  .withColumn("completed_segments", $"segments.completed_segments")
  .where($"url".isNotNull && $"completed_segments".isNotNull)
  .select($"url", $"id".alias("action_id"), $"completed_segments")
```

Regarding you Python code:

- don't use `!=` to compare to `None`. A correct way is to use `is` / `is not`. It is semantically correct (`None` is a singleton) and significantly faster. See also [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- don't duplicate data unless you have to. Emitting `url` twice means a higher memory usage and subsequent network traffic
- if you plan to use SparkSQL check for missing values can be perform on a DataFrame, same as in Scala. I would also persist DataFrame not a RDD.

On a side note I am rather skeptical abut serialization being a real problem here. There is an overhead but a real impact shouldn't be anywhere near to what you've described.